# Hide partially obscured element using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='c1'>hello</div>
  <div class='c2'>bob</div>
</div>

<div class='row'>
  <div class='c1'>this is a very long test test bc a</div>
  <div class='c2'>bob</div>
</div>


<div class='row'>
  <div class='c1'>this is a very long test test test test test</div>
  <div class='c2'>bob</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row .c1 {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.row .c2 {
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
}

.row {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
```

Pen:

http://codepen.io/SamSaffron/pen/JtDHb

Is there some sort of fancy CSS (or HTML5 structure) that can cause `c2` to hide itself as soon as the text in `c1` starts overlapping?

Barring that, what is the best performing JavaScript hack to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you can [hack it with flex box](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bknty) if the rows are a consistent (predetermined) height, but that seems pretty inflexible... (no pun intended)

Comment: Iterating over the `.c1` elements and checking if they overlap the `.c2` siblings is easy enough, but I'm not sure about the best perf approach there.

Comment: I think flex is actually a fine solution here, impressive

Comment: I wasn't positive if it would hold up in your real use case. Proper support also only landed in IE 11, not sure if that's an issue.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT2: Changed the hiding mechanism to `visibility:hidden`, as per suggested by comments.

Here's a solution using jQuery. I'm working on a pure JS solution as well. The same logic should apply.

[CodePen based on yours.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qGnhx)

Basically if the width of `c1` plus `c2` is greater than the width of the `row`, hide `c2`. <del>I added an `overflow:hidden` to the CSS for `c2`, and used `.width(0)` to hide it, since your `c1` has `position:absolute` and so depends on `c2` to provide the height for the row.</del>

Hope that's what you needed.

EDIT: Here's the same solution in pure JavaScript. This assumes that every `row` has a `c1` and a `c2`.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FJemi)

Comment: This flashes which is a bit of a problem, going to need to do an offscreen measure here, also concerned about anything that can cause a reflow.

Comment: @SamSaffron Yeah, I'd probably go for `.visibility = 'hidden';` instead to be on the safe side. Also would have to check if `c1s[i].nextElementSibling` proved better than getting all `.c2` separately...Could also use `c1.getBoundingClientRect().right > c1.nextElementSibling.getBoundingClientRect().left`, but that's probably slower and (likely) requires using the visible elements...Admittedly too lazy to test at the moment.

Comment: I am concerned about using offsetWidth cause of reflows http://mir.aculo.us/2010/08/17/when-does-javascript-trigger-reflows-and-rendering/ may have to render it offscreen so I don't cause a reflow

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can try using the same HTML you have, only with this CSS:

```
.row .c1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 170px;
    max-width: 170px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: red;
    display:table-cell;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}
.row .c2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:-15px
    /* half of the width */
    ;
    background-color: green;
    display:table-cell;
    width:30px;
}
.row {
    display:table;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/seg44ay6/)

Comment: I wouldn't be assuming that the width of `.c2` can be fixed.

Comment: since the container is fixed, he can use percentages and it will work the same

Comment: I still don't think that is a safe assumption. The only safe assumtion to make is to hide `.c2` if the combined content of `.c1` and `.c2` exceed the width of `.row`

Comment: I can see "bob" in all 3 rows, my intention is for it to be absent from the 2nd and 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

I used jquery to solve this problem...

```
$('.row').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('.c1').width()+$(this).find('.c2').width()>$(this).width())
    {
        $(this).find('.c2').css({display:'none'});
        $(this).find('.c1').css({position:'relative'});
    }
  });
```

==> this will automatically takes your .row width , .c2 width n .c1 width as the content may vary

[`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/RajanPaneru/s3p545wx/)

Comment: Rajan, welcome, please see this article on how to format your code in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. The easiest option is to select your code in the editor and click the `{}` button.